# Problem formatting vaadin 8 grid column of object type

Tags: object, formatting, rendering, vaadin-grid

I'm trying to format an Object-type column with the following code. Tried what is suggested to get the column before setting the renderer but I got `null` from `getColumn()`. Can anyone help or point me to a working example of Object-type column formatting?

```
Grid<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> grid = new Grid<>();
.. 

grid.addColumn(h -> h.get(entry.getKey()))
    .setCaption(captn)
    .setStyleGenerator(item -> "v-align-right");
..

if (NumberUtils.isNumber(entry.getValue())) {
  NumberRenderer rdr = new NumberRenderer("###.###,###,###,##");
  Column <LinkedHashMap<String, Object>,Double> col = 
    (Column <LinkedHashMap<String, Object>,Double>)
      grid.getColumn(entry.getKey());
  col.setRenderer(rdr);
}
```

Comment: `grid.getColumn(entry.getKey());` returns `null` because you use a key that you have not set to the column when you added it.

Comment: If you are attempting to change Renderer on the fly, it wont work. You can't have different renderer per Grid row. You can set Renderer for the Grid Column, but all the rows then have the same Renderer.

Comment: thanks for replying, My  grid contains a mixing of string and numeric cols that is built at runtime, i'm trying to use custom renderer for each numeric column.

Comment: The column is created with same key. without the setrenderer codes the grid  is shown correctly but without formatting.  so i know the key i passed in is the correct key for the newly created col

Comment: after further testing using a reference variable from addcolumn(), i found that the col type it created is  Column <LinkedHashMap<String, Object>,Object> whereas the NumberRenderer expects  Column <LinkedHashMap<String, Object>,Double> .is there anyway to do typecast or conversion?

Comment: "is there anyway to do typecast or conversion?", no, the strong typing is there for a purpose. If your column is all same type, you should not use `Object`. If you have mixed types, the case becomes very complex. In theory you could write generic custom renderer that accepts Object and does have logic for selected types and toString as fallback. In general I would review your logic and use case and think again how to implement the view.